# TinyMCE add [removed]// string when submitting javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE to add html content to one page. When I add the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">alert("test")</script>
```

and submit the form, text is changed into this:

```
<p>\n[removed]// &lt;![CDATA[\nalert&#40;"test"&#41;\n// ]]>[removed]\n</p>
```

Here is the tinyMCE configuration:

```
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea:not(.mceNoEditor)',
 allow_script_urls: true,
 extended_valid_elements : "script[type|src]"
});
```

and, according to documentation, it should not remove script code.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code

`tinyMCE.init({
extended_valid_elements : "extended_valid_elements : \"a[class|name|href|target|title|onclick|rel],script[type|src],iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],$elements\","});`

extended_valid_elements setting allow to script tage in tinyMCE.

Comment: you can use this link https://whmcs.community/topic/81029-tinymce-editor-allow-script-tags/

Comment: This is the code: tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea:not(.mceNoEditor)',
  allow_script_urls: true,
  extended_valid_elements : "extended_valid_elements : \"a[class|name|href|target|title|onclick|rel],script[type|src],iframe[src|style|width|height|scrolling|marginwidth|marginheight|frameborder],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],$elements\","
});

Comment: You can use this tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
   extended_valid_elements : "a[class|name|href|target|title|onclick|rel],script[type|sr‌​c],iframe[src|style|‌​width|height|scrolli‌​ng|marginwidth|margi‌​nheight|frameborder]‌​,img[class|src|borde‌​r=0|alt|title|hspace‌​|vspace|width|height‌​|align|onmouseover|o‌​nmouseout|name],$ele‌​ments" ,
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
});

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE is not adding the string `[removed]` to your content - there is nothing in TinyMCE that would do that.

I suspect your application has code to sanitize HTML when you save the content as allowing JavaScript can lead to all sorts of exploits.  Check the documentation for your framework to see if there is some way you can disable this sanitization for certain fields.  That being said *do know that you are opening yourself up for bad things to happen if you allow people to submit arbitrary JavaScript*.